# MongoDB and MongoDB compas cooperation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I installed mongoDB localy as a service by tutorial. But if i connected to DB on sample from w3school

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

there is no error. When i opened Compas i didn't see new DB "mydb". But if i inserted some data to mydb across  application and wrote result to console.log then are theess data returned. But in compas are still not visible. Did you meet with this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: In mongodb compass sometimes you need to hit refresh

Comment: Unfortanetely reload doesn't work. I think that i found the problem, but i don't know what i should to do. I have set dbpath to c:\data\db. And If i run mongod. Mongod is joined to this path. But there is a MongoDB service which has same data structure in Program Files and i think the Compas look here. But i don't know where i have to change this path.